# Call a method from a child view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn

I'm trying to make some changes to the code a colleague made.

So, I have a ShellView that loads documents (and shows them as its content) with a method defined in its ViewModel, and the child view, a StatusBarView which holds the path navigated in the documents and some other infos.

```
public class ShellViewModel 
{
    public StatusBarViewModel StatusBar { get; }

    public ShellViewModel(StatusBarViewModel statusBarViewModel, ...)
    {
        StatusBar = statusBarViewModel;

        var keymap = new Keymap();
        keymap.Map("F2", new SimpleCommand("open-file", 
                                           "Shows the open file dialog", 
                                            param => OpenFile());

    }

    private void OpenFile()
    {
        // Logic to open the file that uses other methods 
        // inside this VM to validate the file
    }
}
```

At the moment you can load a new pack of documents pressing a key, I'd like to do the same with a button in the Status Bar and calling that method.

What is the proper way to call a method existing in the parent view from the child view?

Comment: You parent view create your child view?

Comment: Yes, the child IS the StatusBarView/VM, I added some explanations in the code

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. First need to analyze your purpose.
- You can create an ActionEvent or EventHandler inside childview and on button click you can raise that event.
- Another way use can use Mediator pattern/Observer pattern

Example:
Inside child ViewModel:

```
public event EventHandler openFileEvent;
```

Inside click button action on status bar:

```
private void btnClick()
{
  if(null != openFileEvent)
  {
     openFileEvent(this, new EventArgs{});
  }
}
```

Inside Parent ViewModel:

```
statusBarViewModel.openFileEvent += new EventHandler(EventHandlerName);

private void EventHandlerName(objehct sender, EventArgs...)
{
   ...
   OpenFile();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your child view Define an event Handler

```
public EventHandler OpenFileHandler
```

On the click of the button of your Status Bar view do this:

```
public Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   OpenFileHandler(this, e);
 }
```

in your parent view, when you create your status bar view, define the delegate

```
statusbar.OpenFileHandler+= delegate
{ 
   ShellViewModel instance = this.DataContext as ShellViewModel;
   instance.OpenFile();
}
```

statusbar is the name i gave to your status bar view, but it represent the instance of it

Comment: If you need more control, you can define also custom events args to feed the function that will implement the OpenFileHandler in the Shell view

Comment: The EventHandler defined in StatusBarViewModel doesn't exist in the code behind of the StatusBarView, am I missing something?

Comment: The event handler is defined in the StatusBarView, and is implemented in the Shell view. If you need to do something more complicated (i.e you need something from StatusBarViewModel), you can define a custom EventsArg class, that can store the properties you need

Comment: Ok, when I click the button the application breaks because the EventHandler is null. Sorry, I haven't written the code and there are no comments, it's quite hard for me to understand everything that happens.

Comment: Did you added the delegate on the StatusBarView creation? You gave us not enough code, so i am supposing that you are creating the instance of StatusBarView from your ShellView. If this is the case, just add the last piece of code, after you create a new instance of StatusBarView

Comment: The ShellViewModel creates an instance of the StatusBarViewModel (which then creates the View, I guess). To test your code I added an instance of the StatusBarView in the ShellViewModel constructor.

Comment: thats ugly....a viewmodel isn't suppose to even know that a view exist. So you shouldn't create an instance of your view from the viewmodel

Comment: However, if you decide to keep this approach (which i would absolutely avoid if i were you), the concept of my solutions is still valid. No matter where you create an instance of StatusBarView; you just need to handle the event with a delegate or a custom method (in case you define custom event args)